# Is it possible to reduce the white space inside the cell?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-generation, itext7

[image: Table1]

I selected all text in my table in the picture attached, I want to remove all the white space above and beneath all text so I can fit more data in the table.

I have no idea what to look for cause I don't know how it is called :s

Any help would be great.

Comment: [Tagging help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging): _"The **only time** you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title."_

Comment: Sorry, I do this automatically because of another forum I frequently visit.

Comment: No worries. :-) It's not necessary here since Google does a good job of indexing tags, you can search within a tag on SO itself, and most people who seek to answer questions find them through tags they are interested in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the .SetPadding options for each cell.

**Edit:** I thought this was it but it seems there is still some whitespace and that is because of the font. I didn't find a way yet to strip that off.

**Edit2**: You can use .setPadding with negative values to force it :) !

As an example see code below.

```
            var paragraph = new Paragraph(StrTxt);           
            paragraph .SetFont(FontSpecial);
            paragraph .SetFontSize(24);
            paragraph .SetPaddingTop(-9);
```